# How can I output clang-format results to a file?

Tags: clang, clang-format

I want to use clang-format to dump C/C++ files into disk. I am using this command right now:

```
clang-format file.c
```

which reformat the following source code snippet:

```
int main() {
char name[50];
int marks, i, num;

printf("Enter number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

return 0;
}
```

To:

```
int main() {
  char name[50];
  int marks, i, num;

  printf("Enter number of students: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  return 0;
}
```

But, I do not know how can I dump the output of clang-format to a file instead of dumping the results in terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Inplace edit with -i option.

```
clang-format -i test.c
```

Comment: Thanks. What is inplace meaning here?

Comment: replacing in the same file.